# how do i wrap actual job around the worker_monitor in base class after performing of async job?

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

worker_monitor is a table which will store the status of the worker.
there is a method run! which will execute the async by calling the worker. And the worker is a sidekick worker.
eg.

```
module Mymodule
 Class MyClass

  def run!(action_name, args)
    ModuleName::WorkerName.perform_async(action_name,args)
  end

  def update_worker_monitor_status
    initialize worker_monitor # this will initialize the worker_monitor
    wrap actual job run here
    handle exception
  end
 end
end
```

How do i wrap the actual job? please suggest

Answer (score 0):

By using server-side middleware, as documented in the wiki: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Middleware#server-middleware